# Style an Order list number using tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

Good day, im trying to style an ol list number using tailwindcss and  cant seem to do it, i have research through google with no luck. thank you for your help.

the framework is different from vanilla css, i cant seem to find same syntax with tailwindcss as it is on vanilla css

Comment: Please add the code including the HTML and CSS you have tried TO your question and describe your specific one challenge with that code so we can best assist you here.

Answer (score 10):

To style an ordered list in tailwind, you will need to apply some list utilities to the `ol` element and use the `marker:` state on the items you would like to style.

First, the numbers won't be visible if you create an ordered list. To display the numbers, we need to apply those two utilities to the `ol` container:

1. `list-decimal` - Set the style of the list to numbers. [Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type)
2. `list-inside` - Set the number's position inside the `ol` element. [Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-position)

```html
<ol class="list-decimal list-inside">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

This way, we get a regular ordered list of items without any styling:

[image: order-list without styling]

---

If you want to style a specific `li` element, use the `marker:` state. You can use the `marker:` state either on a specific `li` element or the `ol` element to apply styling to all the items in the list.

You can read more about the `marker:` state in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#list-markers).

In the below example, we set the text's color of the `ol` elements to blue by applying `marker:text-blue-700`. Then, we set the text of the first `li` element to red using `marker:text-red-700`. This way, we get the following:

[image: ordered list]

```html
<ol class="list-decimal list-inside marker:text-blue-700">
  <li class="marker:text-red-700">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ysImjClVGI)